# How to get first tag into variable wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the text of the first tag into a php variable in a template so I can use it for something. I am trying to do this in single.php

i find this one but it not work as i expected

```
<?php
$tag = get_the_tags();
if ($tag) {
$tag = $tag[0]; echo $tag->name;
}
?>
```

so it is possible get first tag into variable also link too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code inside the while loop in your single.php file :

```
$allposttags = get_the_tags();
                $i=0;
                if ($allposttags) {
                    foreach($allposttags as $tags) {
                        $i++;
                        if (1 == $i) {
                            $firsttag = $tags->name;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now you can use $firsttag variable where you want to show first tag of the current post.

Comment: Thanks Vidhu Nair giving me idea to improve above code                                                                   $allposttags = get_the_tags();
                $i=0;
                if ($allposttags) {
                    foreach($allposttags as $tags) {
                        $i++;
                        if (1 == $i) {
                            $firsttag = $tags->name;
                            $tag=$firsttag;
                            $tag_link=get_tag_link($tags->term_id);
                        }
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your single.php,

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$count=0;
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $count++;
    if (1 == $count) {
      echo '<a href='.get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'>'.$tag->name . ' </a>';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$allposttags = get_the_tags();
                $i=0;
                if ($allposttags) {
                    foreach($allposttags as $tags) {
                        $i++;
                        if (1 == $i) {
                            $firsttag = $tags->name;
                            $tag=$firsttag;
                            $tag_link=get_tag_link($tags->term_id);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

echo $tag;
echo $tag_link;

Answer (score 0):

```
// get all tags
$tags = get_the_tags();
// get the first tag
// $first_tag return Object with term_id, name, slug, term_group, term_taxonomy_id, // taxonomy, description, parent, count, filter
$first_tag = (isset($tags[0]) && !empty($tags[0])) ? $tags[0] : '';
// echo tag name example
echo (isset($first_tag->name) && !empty($first_tag->name)) ? $first_tag->name : '';
```